# Profiling node application: most time spent in node itself

Tags: node.js, profiling

I am using a node application that is experiencing a performance problem under certain loads.  I am attempting to use the V8 profiler to find out where the problem might be, basically following [this guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/).

I've generated a log file during the problem load using `node --prof app.js`, and analyzed it with `node --prof-process isolate-0xnnnnnnnnnnnn-v8.log > processed.txt`.  This all seems to work fine, but it seems that almost all the ticks are spent in the node executable itself:

```
 [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   3887    5.8%   38.2%  JavaScript
   5590    8.4%   55.0%  C++
    346    0.5%    3.4%  GC
  56296   84.7%          Shared libraries
    689    1.0%          Unaccounted
```

and:

```
 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  55990   84.2%          /usr/bin/node
    225    0.3%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
     68    0.1%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
      7    0.0%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
      4    0.0%          [vdso]
      2    0.0%          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
```

What does this mean?  What is the app spending all its time doing?  How can I find the performance problem?

Comment: Well of course! First, you need to see the stack samples, so you know *why* it's spending the time. Routine percents don't tell you anything. Second, it could be spending nearly all of its time waiting for a system call like I/O, and if it were you would need to see the stack samples leading to the I/O so you could see what it was waiting for. Most profilers brag that they are *CPU Profiler*s. Know what that means? They are ***blind to I/O***, no matter how much time it wastes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try VTune Amplifier as alternative of the V8 profiler. I was able to identify and fix the time-consuming place in my code. You can download free trial version [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) and just follow by this [step-by-step instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-cookbook-profiling-javascript-code-in-node-js). Hope it will help you.